# Azure Function secured with AAD

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad

I have created an HTTP triggered azure function secured with AAD.
User need to consent the app explicitly to make it work.

How can an admin grant access on behalf of organisation so that individual users will no longer receive consent popup?

Permissions for Azure AD app:
Sign in and read user profiles under delegate permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go to the Azure portal, find appropriate app registration (you can search by App Id used for securing Azure function), then select the app by clicking on it, then Settings -> Required permissions -> Grant Permissions -> Yes:

[image]